# Looping variable after another loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

i'm trying to loop a variable whose data populates from another loop of array's

**HERE is the loop**

```
for ($i=0; $i < $cid; $i++){
$message .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$pcode.'</td>
            <td>'.$pname.'</td>
            <td>'.$pprice.'</td>
            <td>'.$pqty.'</td>
            </tr>';
}
```

**And the variables in `<td></td>` are generated from this loop**

```
foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) {

$cid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value);
$pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]);
$pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]);
$pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]);
$pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

}
```

I don't know how to make this loop work, I got no errors on submit,

**am i looping it correctly?**

**The Updated Code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
require('admin/connect.php');
require('includes/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$resultArr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) {
//Data for Orders Table
    $cid = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value));
    $pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]);
    $pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]);
    $pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]);
    $pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

//SOLUTION FROM SANJAY
    $resultArr[$i] = array('cid' => $cid, 'pcode' => $pcode, 'pname' => $pname, 'pprice' => $pprice, 'pqty' => $pqty);
    $i++;

//Data for Customers Table
    $cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cname'][$key]);
    $cemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cemail'][$key]);
    $cphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cphone'][$key]);
    $caddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_caddress'][$key]);
    $ctotal = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_ctotal'][$key]);


//$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (cid, ordprod_code, ordprod_name, ordprod_price, ordprod_qty) VALUES ('$value', '$pcode', '$pname', '$pprice', '$pqty')";
//$sql2 = "INSERT INTO customers (cid, cname, cemail, cphone, caddress, ctotal) VALUES ('$value','$cname','$cemail','$cphone','$caddress','$ctotal')";
    if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Orders record created successfully \n";
    }
//     } else {
//        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
//     }

    if ($connection->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        echo "Customers record created successfully \n";
    }
//    } else {
//        echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $connection->error;


} // close the loop

print_r($resultArr);

//********************************
// START EMAIL FUNCTION
//********************************

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<a href="http://www.example.com/"><img src="http://cdn.example.com/static/images/emailhead.jpg" alt="MY Site" /></a>';
$message .= '<h3>Customer Information:</h3>'; 
$message .= '<table rules="all" border="1" style="border-color: #ccc;" cellpadding="10">'; 
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>CustomerID</strong></td><td>'. $cid .'</td></tr>'; 
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong></td><td>'. $cname .'</td></tr>'; 
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong></td><td>'. $cemail .'</td></tr>'; 
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong></td><td>'. $cphone .'</td></tr>'; 
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong></td><td>'. $caddress .'</td></tr>'; 
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '<br />';
$message .= '<h3>Order Details:</h3>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" border="1" style="border-color: #ccc;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= '<tr style="background:#eee;">
            <td><strong>Product Code</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Product Price</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Product Qty</strong></td>
            </tr>';

// SOLUTION FROM SANJAY

$i = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < ((isset($resultArr[$i]['cid']) && count($resultArr[$i]['cid']) > 0 ) ?$resultArr[$i]['cid'] : 0); $i++)

{
$message .= '<tr>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pcode'].'</td>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pname'].'</td>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pprice'].'</td>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pqty'].'</td>
         </tr>';
}

$message .= '<tr style="background:#eee;">
            <td colspan="2">Total Amount</td>
            <td>'.$ctotal.'</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>';             
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '</body></html>'; 

$pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i"; 
if (preg_match($pattern, $cemail)) { 
$cleanedFrom = $cemail; 
} else { 
return "The email address you entered was invalid. Please try again!"; 
} 

//***************************************
// SEND MAIL USING GMAIL SMTP SERVER
//***************************************
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
$mail->setFrom(''.$cemail.'', ''.$cname.'');     //Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->addReplyTo(''.$cemail.'', ''.$cname.'');  //Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addAddress('owner@example.com', 'YAQOOB');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('owner@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addCC('');
$mail->addBCC('');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/user/file.doc');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/images/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'New order arrived from CustomerID #'.$cid.'';
$mail->Body    = ''.$message.'';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
//$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';

} // Data Inserted & Emailed Close IF Statement 


session_destroy();  
?>
```

Comment: How are you getting the `$cid` like of variable outside the loop

Comment: From a hidden Input within `$_POST`

Comment: But within your code I can't figure it out. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: $cid, $cname, $cphone and other variables in foreach has different value in each step through the loop and you use those variables ONCE after the loop, thats wrong, isnt it?...I think you have to do all the rest with message IN this foreach; not outside it...If i am wrong, correct me :)

Comment: @NarendraSisodia The `$cid` is actually `$_POST['item_cid']`

Comment: @zdeniiik can you give me the example within my code? becuase when i tried i have got errors for every variable calls. saying `Undefined variable`

Comment: @yaqoob you are assigining `$cid` like of variable within loop not outside loop check it yourself and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @NarendraSisodia the `$cid` is inside of the loop

Comment: @yaqoob Great so you identified it, now you can also define why you got `Undefined variable` error for every variables.

Comment: I edit my answer, it's just a hint, check it. Just did all in foreach loop.

Comment: @NarendraSisodia When i follow @zdeniiik solution i got the undefined error. What i did is that, i divided the message variables into 3 parts by moving up the `for ($i=0; $i < $cid; $i++)` into the  `foreach` loop as asked,

Comment: @yaqoob what variable is undefined? I am almost clueless :( :D

Comment: @zdeniiik all the variables that are called in the for loop

Comment: @yaqoob and declaring them like $message above foreach will not help i suppose (I'm not on a computer running PHP, so I cant try)...I'm running out of ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$message = "";
$resultArr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) 
{
   $cid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value);
   $pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]);
   $pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]);
   $pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]);
   $pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);
   $resultArr[$i] = array('cid' => $cid, 'pcode' => $pcode, 'pname' => $pname, 'pprice' => $pprice, 'pqty' => $pqty);
   $i++;
}
$i = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < (isset($resultArr[$i]['cid']) && $resultArr[$i]['cid'] ?$resultArr[$i]['cid'] : 0); $i++)
{
$message .= '<tr>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pcode'].'</td>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pname'].'</td>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pprice'].'</td>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pqty'].'</td>
         </tr>';
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74730/discussion-on-answer-by-sanjay-kumar-n-s-looping-variable-after-another-loop).

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
$message = "";
foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) 
{
   $cid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value);
   $pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]);
   $pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]);
   $pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]);
   $pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

   for ($i=0; $i < $cid; $i++)
   {
   $message .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$pcode.'</td>
            <td>'.$pname.'</td>
            <td>'.$pprice.'</td>
            <td>'.$pqty.'</td>
            </tr>';
   }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do that after the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @yaqoob why after? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Your $cid,$pcode,$pname and other variables are changing in every step in foreach, so you should do this in foreach I think...Or you could store all values of variables to array and process it later, but I think this solution is better

Comment: @UserProg in the `foreach` loop there's alot of stuff going on, like SQL quiries (Inserting) and all. It will complicate the code i just want the `$message` part separate. is that possible?

Comment: @yaqoob yes it is. You have to store the variable in an array and then continue processing it outside. Refer answer by Sanjay below

Comment: @zdeniiik tried your updated answer, but the results are an infinite loop of errors/notices :(

Comment: Oh, sorry, I took the revision back.